# Line breaks are ignored

Tags: 7, commerce

This is the only filter defined:

[image]

but the the line breaks are removed and multiple paragraphs are joined into one paragraph.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Guaranteed you are using the wrong text format when actually going to edit content!

Comment: Are you using a WYSIWYG editor such as CKeditor or TinyMCE? WYSIWYG editors can be configured to remove linebreaks, making the "Convert line breaks into HTML" filter useless.

Comment: @marcvangend I am not sure. It's a new site from the default kickstart.

Comment: When you enter text in such a text field, does it have text editing buttons like [**B**] and [_I_] above it? If so, it's a WYSIWYG editor. If you can only type plain text, it's not. But anyway, if this is the out-of-the-box behavior of the [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) distribution, you better add a bug report in their [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_kickstart?).

Comment: It seems to be a bug: http://drupal.org/node/1019042